# c++ QT QUdp socket not sending / receiving data?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, udp

According to this page https://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/Query_Mechanism I can send some data to the host and it will respond with some information to me, am I correct? 
if no I would be thankful if any one could help me in this.

However I am doing the below codes but it just simple doing nothing O.O any one know what I am doing wrong?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <qmessagebox.h>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QUdpSocket *mysock = new QUdpSocket(this);
    mysock->writeDatagram("i", QHostAddress("164.132.69.65"), 7777);
    QByteArray myarry;
    QHostAddress myhost;
    quint16 port;
    mysock->readDatagram(myarry.data(), myarry.size(), &myhost, &port);
    ui->textEdit->setText(myarry.data());
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

myarry.data() is just simple empty ;-;....

Comment: You must return to the event loop to finish sending your datagram. At the time you do a read, it's still in the output buffer, waiting to be sent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`QUdpSocket::readDatagram()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html#readDatagram) (and most Qt network IO functions) do **not** block until data is available. This means that if you call it at a point where no data has arrived yet, you'll not have any data in the buffer you provided and the call should return `-1`.

From the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html#details):

> The `readyRead()` signal is emitted whenever datagrams arrive. In that
>   case, `hasPendingDatagrams()` returns true. Call `pendingDatagramSize()`
>   to obtain the size of the first pending datagram, and `readDatagram()`
>   to read it.

You should be calling `readDatagram()` from a slot that is connected to the `readyRead()` signal.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //mysock should be a member of the MainWindow class
    //so that you can access it from other functions
    mysock = new QUdpSocket(this);
    mysock->writeDatagram("i", QHostAddress("164.132.69.65"), 7777);
    connect(mysock, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &MainWindow::readPendingDatagrams);
}

//add this slot to the class's declaration
void MainWindow::readPendingDatagrams(){
    //read datagrams in a loop to make sure that all received datagrams are processed
    //since readyRead() is emitted for a datagram only when all previous datagrams are read
    while(mysock->hasPendingDatagrams()){
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(mysock->pendingDatagramSize());
        QHostAddress sender;
        quint16 senderPort;

        mysock->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(),
                                &sender, &senderPort);

        //do whatever you want to received datagram
        ui->textEdit->setText(datagram.data());
    }
}
```

---

#### Edit:

Looks like the request you are sending to the server does not conform to the specifications in [your link](https://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/Query_Mechanism#The_backbone_of_packets). In your code, you are just sending an `"i"` letter and nothing else.

The page denotes (in brief) that you should send the prefix `"SAMP"` followed by the server's ip then the server's port, after that you can send your opcode (which is `"i"` in your case).

Putting that altogether, Here is how I would implement it:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //mysock should be a member of the MainWindow class
    //so that you can access it from other functions
    mysock = new QUdpSocket(this);
    QHostAddress serverAddress("164.132.69.65");
    quint16 port= 7777;
    QByteArray data;
    //building request
    data+= "SAMP";      //"SAMP" prefix
    //convert to big endian to make sure the octets are sent in the specified order
    quint32 ipv4AddrBigEndian= qToBigEndian(serverAddress.toIPv4Address());
    //convert to little endian to make sure port bytes are sent in the specified order
    quint16 portLittleEndian= qToLittleEndian(port);
    //add server ip address
    data.append(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ipv4AddrBigEndian), sizeof(ipv4AddrBigEndian));
    //add server port
    data.append(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&portLittleEndian), sizeof(portLittleEndian));
    //add opcode
    data.append("i");
    mysock->writeDatagram(data, serverAddress, port);
    connect(mysock, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &MainWindow::readPendingDatagrams);
}


void MainWindow::readPendingDatagrams(){
    //read datagrams in a loop to make sure that all received datagrams are processed
    //since readyRead() is emitted for a datagram only when all previous datagrams are read
    while(mysock->hasPendingDatagrams()){
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(mysock->pendingDatagramSize());
        QHostAddress sender;
        quint16 senderPort;

        mysock->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(),
                                &sender, &senderPort);

        qDebug() << "received: " << datagram.toHex();

        //do whatever you want to received datagram
        //you need to parse information you want from the datagram
        //It can NOT be just displayed as text in a QTextEdit (as it contains binary data)
    }
}
```

The format of the server's binary reply that you need to parse is specified in the page you linked [here](https://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/Query_Mechanism#Response_from_i).

---

#### Side Note:

I really think that you should separate out building requests and parsing responses in their own class, instead of having all of that in the `MainWindow` class (which should be used for the definition of the UI and nothing else).

Comment: I've tried your code but readPendingDatagrams never gets called... :'c

Comment: Are you sure the other end is *really* sending anything back? please use a sniffer tool like wireshark to confirm that. You are using UDP, there is no any guarantee that some host really exists at *"164.132.69.65"* and that it has received your sent datagram .

Comment: there's no problem with the host, I have already made a application in c# which getting the information without any problems it just working perfectly!, Idk what's wrong with c++ :'c